# OpenAPI Generator: Generating APIs in the same parent path to different API classes

Tags: java, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

We are using openapi generator to generate API classes and we noticed that all APIs under base path generated into one API class.
For example: /clusters/{id}/servers and /messages/{id}/storages goes to ClustersApi.java

Is there a way to configure them to generate ServersApi and StorgesApi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe this is possible with the current implementation. You may want to follow this ticket https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/6595